# determining whether Lie algebra is enlarged by new generator

Tags: lie-algebras

Is there a simple criterion to determine whether, given a set of generators $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of a Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}\subset\mathfrak{g}$, adding a new element $B\in\mathfrak{g}$ will enlarge the subalgebra? Clearly if $B$ is in the linear span of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, the subalgebra is not enlarged, but if this is not the case, is there anything to do other than actually list out all of the nested commutators of the $A_i$ and check that $B$ is linearly independent of them?

Comment: Generators and relations for a Lie algebra are defined by a quotient $L/R$, where $L$ is free on a set $X$, and relator ideal $R$, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=gv2Xf8VVi2MC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=generators+and+relations+for+Lie+algebras&source=bl&ots=w8B1iyiVas&sig=ohwAaNWcdr7lndKmA3PcoOeW0Lo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy_t6MmszKAhWCtBoKHXY7A-gQ6AEIUjAG#v=onepage&q=generators%20and%20relations%20for%20Lie%20algebras&f=false), $9.4$. It seems that you understand something different by "generator". A "new " linear independent vector $B$ need not be a new generator.

Comment: Yes, I don't mean generator in the sense of free algebras, but in the sense that $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ are a set of generators for a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ if $\mathfrak{g}$ is the smallest Lie algebra containing the $A_i$. Is there another name? An (obviously trivial) example of what I'm asking is, suppose $\mathfrak{h}$ is the smallest Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ containing $\left\lbrace X,Y\right\rbrace\subset\mathfrak{su}(2)$ the usual Pauli matrices and $\mathfrak{h}'$ is the smallest Lie algebra containing $\left\lbrace X,Y,Z\right\rbrace$, is $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{h}'$?